# Theorem Name/Numbering in Margin

Tags: positioning, margins, theorems

I have seen the previous discussion on this same issue before (see [Theorem name and number in margin, note in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13578/theorem-name-and-number-in-margin-note-in-text)), however this did not resolve anything as clearly as I had hoped.

Basically, I would like to have a visible margin (i.e:- a vertical line) on the left hand side of the page. Within the margin, I would like the section numbers (but not the name), equations numbers, theorem names and their respective numbers, but I am a bit a newbie in LaTeX and am I unsure how to go about doing this.

An example with the symbol "|" denoting the position of the margin would be:

```
                3.1. | Continuous Groups
                     |
      Definition 3.1 | Lie Group:.....
             (3.1.1.)| [SOME EQUATION HERE]
      Definition 3.2 | Lie Algebra:....
```

Thank you in advance.

Just some points of clarification (updated, based on the comments)
1. The document is one-sided, so only the left-hand side margin is of relevance.
2. Any suggestions on which theorem packages will be more suitable are welcome.

Comment: Just to clarify: this pretty much means your document is one-sided, so it's always the left margin, not the outer margin, right?

Comment: Correct, it is always the left margin of every page.

Comment: Thank you for help on that bit. And I flexible with regards to any of the packages you have suggested as I have not yet started writing up the document (I have just been researching about this topic before I begin).

Comment: Future users may find the following an improvement on the accepted answer. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/277731/18414

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think the following does what you want.

[image: screenshot]

The packages I have used are

- `esopic` to add the gray vertical bar to the margin
- `titlesec` to customize the section numbers using `\llap`
- `ntheorem` to create a customized definition environment- you could equivalently use `amsthm`, but I'm more familiar with `ntheorem`

I've borrowed some code/ideas from

- [Changing the appearance of equation numbers with amsmath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28903/changing-the-apperance-of-equation-numbers-with-amsmath)
- [How can I align section titles and list environments in the left margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33137/how-can-i-align-section-titles-and-list-environments-in-the-left-margin)

Code:

```
   % arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: on}
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor}                 % to have colors 
\usepackage{eso-pic}                % put things into background 
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % for sample text
\usepackage{titlesec}     % for customizing sections
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}         % for mathematical content
\usepackage[amsmath]{ntheorem}      % for theorem-like environments

% customize the tag form of the equations
\makeatletter
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\hbox{\llap{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\hspace{1mm}}}}\kern1sp}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{{\mytagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother

% customize section
\titleformat{\section}%
{\Large\bfseries}% format
{\llap{% label
    \thesection\hskip 9pt}}%
{0pt}% horizontal sep
{}% before

% customize subsection
\titleformat{\subsection}%
{\bfseries}% format
{\llap{% label
    \thesubsection\hskip 9pt}}%
{0pt}% horizontal sep
{}% before

% add vertical bar- change colour and thickness as desired
\AddToShipoutPicture{% from package eso-pic: put something to the background
    % 3. Text area
    \AtTextLowerLeft{% put it at the left bottom of the text area
        \llap{\color{gray}\rule{.1cm}{\LenToUnit\textheight}% can put spacing here, e.g \hspace{.25cm}
        }%
    }%
}

% margin theorem
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mymargin}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{##1 ##2}]}%
{\item[\theorem@headerfont \llap{##1 ##2}| ##3\theorem@separator\hskip\labelsep]}%
\makeatother

% my definition
\theoremstyle{mymargin}
\theorembodyfont{}      % customize these to suit your tastes
\theoremsymbol{}
\theoremprework{}
\theorempostwork{}
\theoremseparator{}
\newtheorem{mydefinition}{Definition}
\numberwithin{mydefinition}{section}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mydefinition}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:myequation}
    f(x)=x^2
\end{equation}
Test reference: \eqref{eq:myequation}
\end{mydefinition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, this is an excellent response. And just what I am looking for. Thank you very much. All I have to now is adjust the text is so it is not close to the margin, and align the equation to the line of its number, but other than that, this perfect. Thank you very much @cmhughes.

Comment: just a question of interest, how can this be in "amsthm" as well?

Comment: @MP1510 glad it helped; I'm afraid I'm not so familiar with `amsthm`. I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @MP1510 there was a small problem with the vertical alignment of the equation label- I fixed it in the edit

Comment: @ cmhughes: thank you for the correction. I normally use the environment flalign so (for some strange reason) so this slight error never came up for the vertical alignment.

Comment: However, I do have one question: the equation label becomes horizontally shifted if I had placed an equation within text of an \item in the \itemize or \enumerate list environments - is there any way around this?

Comment: @MP1510 I don't know how to fix this immediately- perhaps a new question would be in order, including a MWE

Comment: reference: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277716/using-llap-in-titleformat-prevents-line-breaking