# empheq and changing location of equation numbers

Tags: empheq

I am using the empheq/tcolorbox packages to put colored boxes around my equations but would like to place the equation numbers in the right margin.

In the past, I have used the following code to put equation numbers in the right margin and it has worked outside of the empheq environment.  If I use it within empheq, I get no equation numbers but the references exist.

```
\makeatletter
\let\mytagform@=\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\hbox{\rlap{\hspace{0.5in}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}}\kern1sp}
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{{\mytagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\makeatother
```

Below is a MWE.  `\margtrue`places equation numbers in margin while `\margfalse` will exhibit the "normal" behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newif\ifmarg
\margtrue

\ifmarg
    \makeatletter
    \let\mytagform@=\tagform@
    \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\hbox{\rlap{\hspace{0.5in}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}}\kern1sp}
    \renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{{\mytagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
    \makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}
    An equation with number in the right margin.
    \begin{gather}
        F = ma.
    \end{gather}
    And now an equation within an \verb|empheq| environment.
    \begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{gather}
        F = ma.
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

The `\margtrue` behavior is shown below.  Note the second equation does not have any equation number displayed.

[image]

The `\margfalse` behavior is shown below.  Note the second equation does have an equation number displayed (not in margin though).

[image]

Comment: As always on this site, please post a full minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not initially sure why (see **FOLLOW UP** following this initial discussion),  but I found that placing an `\mbox{~}` (or even just a `~`) before the `\hbox` in the definition of `\maketag@@@` makes it work.  However, `\mbox{}` does not fix the problem (which rules out the issue being one of vertical versus horizontal mode.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newif\ifmarg
\margtrue

\ifmarg
    \makeatletter
    \let\mytagform@=\tagform@
    \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{\mbox{~}\hbox{\rlap{\hspace{0.5in}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}}\kern1sp}
    \renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{{\mytagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
    \makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}
    An equation with number in the right margin.
    \begin{gather}
        F = ma.
    \end{gather}
    And now an equation within an \verb|empheq| environment.
    \begin{empheq}[box=\tcbhighmath]{gather}
        F = ma.
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOLLOW UP**

The behavior seems dependent on whether the `\maketag@@@` definition has non-zero width.  For example, `\makebox[0.001pt]{}` or even `\kern1pt` prior to the `\hbox` works, too, but `\makebox[0pt]{}` does not.  I suspect an `\ifdim...>0pt` test somewhere.

And here, [Why isn't a zero-width box in math mode aligned on the baseline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78599/why-isnt-a-zero-width-box-in-math-mode-aligned-on-the-baseline), David says "A zero width equation number is used as a flag to get special handling" and then references the TeXbook (p.189): "One consequence of these rules is that you can force an equation number to appear on a line by itself by making its width zero."

I suspect it is this "special handling" that is interfering with the OP's original attempt, since the `\margtrue` setting forces the tag width to be zero, by virtue of it being an `\rlap`.

In fact, the TeXbook discussion, on page 188, defines *e* as the width of the equation number:

"Let *q* and *e* be zero if there is no equation
number; otherwise let *e* be the width of the equation number

...

"If *e* [not equal] 0 and if there is enough
shrinkability in the displayed formula h to reduce its width to *z* − *q*, then list *h* is
packaged in an `hbox` *b* of width *z* −*q*. Otherwise *e* is set to zero, and list *h* is packaged
in a (possibly overfull) `hbox` *b* of width `min`(*w*_0, *z*).

...

"If there was an `\eqno` and if *e* = 0, an infinite
penalty is placed on the vertical list, followed by the equation number box *a* shifted
right by *s*+ *z* minus its width, followed by a penalty item whose cost is the value
of `\postdisplaypenalty`."

Comment: Perfect - thanks.  Not sure why either but hey, it works!

Comment: @user2501235 Please see my FOLLOW UP for more information.