# Using llap in titleformat prevents line breaking

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I would like section numbers to be placed in the margin. I found a solution here ([Theorem Name/Numbering in Margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59244/theorem-name-numbering-in-margin)) which works with a caveat: when the section title is very long, the title text line does not break. Explicit breaks (using `\\` or `\newline`) don't work either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\titleformat{\section}%
            {\Large\sffamily\bfseries}% format
            {\llap{% label
               \thesection\hskip 12pt}#1}%
            {0pt}% horizontal sep
            {}% before

\begin{document}
 \section{A long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
 Normal text.
\end{document}
```

I don't fully understand what `\llap` does, but I'm more interested in a solution that keeps the section numbers in the margin but allows the section title to line break. Using KOMA classes is fine, though I understand that may mean not using `titlesec`.

Comment: \llap{} overlaps text to the left.  It should have no effect on line breaking outside the \llap{}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're putting `#1` in the wrong place: the title is the *last* argument. Without the `explicit` option (that is usually unnecessary) the code should be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\titleformat{\section}%
  {\Large\sffamily\bfseries}% format
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{\thesection\hspace{12pt}}}% label
  {0pt}% horizontal sep
  {}% title

\begin{document}
 \section{A long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
 Normal text.
\end{document}
```

If you prefer having `explicit`, the last line should be

```
  {#1}% title
```

[image]

Don't use `\llap` if you don't know how it works. Prefer `\makebox[0pt][r]{...}`: box with zero width, content pushed to its right margin.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this...  The `\llap` has nothing to do with the problem.  But what I did change was to take `#1` and place it inside of a `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}

\titleformat{\section}%
            {\Large\sffamily\bfseries}% format
            {\llap{% label
               \thesection\hskip 12pt}\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{#1}}%
            {0pt}% horizontal sep
            {}% before

\begin{document}
 \section{A long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
 Normal text.
\end{document}
```

[image]