# Strange side effect of option strict for package changepage

Tags: changepage

I thought my [previous problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399157/theorem-name-number-and-note-in-margin-column-with-amsthm) on placing names, numbers and notes of theorems in the margin column had been solved.

In fact, the code proposed in my answer works as expected:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=classic]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoption{mpinclude}{true}
\recalctypearea
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{10em}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\RaggedOuter}%
{%
  \if@twoside%
    \checkoddpage%
    \ifoddpage%
      \RaggedRight%
    \else%
      \RaggedLeft%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \RaggedRight%
  \fi%
}

\newcommand{\cl@ThmMarginCaption}%
{
  \leavevmode%
  \marginpar%
  {%
    \RaggedOuter%
    \hbadness=10000%
    \the\thm@headfont\thmt@thmname~\thechapter.\arabic{\thmt@envname}\\%
    \the\thm@notefont\thmt@optarg%
  }%
}

\declaretheoremstyle%
[%
  spaceabove={\parskip},%
  spacebelow=0pt,%
  headindent=0pt,%
  postheadspace=0pt,%
  headformat={},%
  headpunct={},%
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries\small,%
  notefont=\rmfamily\mdseries\small,%
  bodyfont=\normalfont,%
  preheadhook={},%
  postheadhook={\cl@ThmMarginCaption},%
]%
{thmmcaption}

\newcommand{\DeclareTheorem}[2][]%
{%
  \declaretheorem[#1]{#2}%
  \expandafter\let\csname cl@orig@#2\expandafter\endcsname\csname#2\endcsname%
  \expandafter\let\csname cl@orig@end#2\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#2\endcsname%
  \renewenvironment{#2}[1][]%
    {\csname cl@orig@#2\endcsname[##1]\ignorespaces}%
    {\csname cl@orig@end#2\endcsname}%
}

\DeclareTheorem[name=Definition, numberwithin=chapter, style=thmmcaption]{definition}
\DeclareTheorem[name=Satz,       numberwithin=chapter, style=thmmcaption]{theorem}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Theorems with margin captions}

\blindtext

\begin{definition}[Kellerautomat (KA)\\pushdown automaton (PDA)]
Eine ganz wichtige Definition, die natürlich länger als eine Zeile sein sollte, um sehen zu können, ob alles funktioniert wie gewünscht.
\end{definition}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\blindtext

\begin{theorem}[Satz von Radó]
Die Radó-Funktion ist nicht berechenbar.
\end{theorem}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The margin note containing the theorem information is placed at the desired position.

[image: Correct position of the margin note]

As soon as I started mixing this solution with other code, the option `strict` for package `changepage` became mandatory. Using this option, the margin note gets shifted down, as you can see here.

[image: Wrong position of the margin note]

Adding `%` at the end of each line of `changepage.sty` when it was not present did not help at all.

Why does the option `strict` have an effect on my definition of `\RaggedOuter`?

Comment: don't use a `%` here! `\hbadness=10000%` or if you must, use ` `\hbadness=10000 %`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I removed the `%` character. The vertical shift of the margin note, however, remains unchanged.

Comment: yes that was unrelated issue,  sorry should have said that:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the strict form in horizontal mode so it does not force a change in linespacing, also beware misusing `%`

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=classic]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\KOMAoption{mpinclude}{true}
\recalctypearea
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{10em}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\RaggedOuter}
{%
  \if@twoside
    \leavevmode\checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage
      \RaggedRight
    \else
      \RaggedLeft
    \fi
  \else
    \RaggedRight
  \fi
  \ignorespaces}

\newcommand{\cl@ThmMarginCaption}
{
  \leavevmode
  \marginpar
  {%
    \RaggedOuter
    \hbadness=10000
    \the\thm@headfont\thmt@thmname~\thechapter.\arabic{\thmt@envname}\\%
    \the\thm@notefont\thmt@optarg
  }%
}

\declaretheoremstyle
[
  spaceabove={\parskip},
  spacebelow=0pt,
  headindent=0pt,
  postheadspace=0pt,
  headformat={},
  headpunct={},
  headfont=\sffamily\bfseries\small,
  notefont=\rmfamily\mdseries\small,
  bodyfont=\normalfont,
  preheadhook={},
  postheadhook={\cl@ThmMarginCaption},
]
{thmmcaption}

\newcommand{\DeclareTheorem}[2][]
{%
  \declaretheorem[#1]{#2}%
  \expandafter\let\csname cl@orig@#2\expandafter\endcsname\csname#2\endcsname
  \expandafter\let\csname cl@orig@end#2\expandafter\endcsname\csname end#2\endcsname
  \renewenvironment{#2}[1][]%
    {\csname cl@orig@#2\endcsname[##1]\ignorespaces}
    {\csname cl@orig@end#2\endcsname}
}

\DeclareTheorem[name=Definition, numberwithin=chapter, style=thmmcaption]{definition}
\DeclareTheorem[name=Satz,       numberwithin=chapter, style=thmmcaption]{theorem}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Theorems with margin captions}

\blindtext

\begin{definition}[Kellerautomat (KA)\\pushdown automaton (PDA)]
Eine ganz wichtige Definition, die natürlich länger als eine Zeile sein sollte, um sehen zu können, ob alles funktioniert wie gewünscht.
\end{definition}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\blindtext

\begin{theorem}[Satz von Radó]
Die Radó-Funktion ist nicht berechenbar.
\end{theorem}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick replay. You saved my day (more precisely, my night). By the way, what is the general rule when to use `%` at the end of a line in the definition of a command and when not?

Comment: @Matthias an end of line is a space, so you just need an end of line if you want a space ir comment it out if you don't. After a `\foo` spaces are ignored so most of your `%` were harmless but did nothing at all, but you need a space to terminate the numeric literal 10000 so having the `%` there is a bad idea, in this case it just meant that `\the\thm@headfont` was expanded before `\hbadness` was set not afterwards but you can get lots of strange bugs by changing the expansion order in that way.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and your patience with me. Though I studied computer science (some time ago) I guess I will never be able to know what really happens "inside" TeX and LaTeX. Good to know that at least some people do ... ;-)