# Creating a layout where theorems are in 'margins'

Tags: sectioning, theorems, sections-paragraphs, book-design, ntheorem

I wish to design a document with the following mock-up layout, where theorems are separated from the main body of the text in a sort of margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
%Underlining ruler for subsections
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% format
  {}% label
  {0mm}% sep
  {%
    \vadjust pre{%
      \color{gray}%
      \hrule width \linewidth height 0.5pt\relax
    }%
  }% before-code

\begin{document}

\section{Example Section}

\end{document}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can take a look at the documentation of `ntheorem`: a `\theoremindent` length is defined, which is 0 by default. Other suggestion: the same package defines a `margin` theorem style.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Theorem name, number and note in margin column with amsthm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399157/).

Comment: While there are similarities here, it is not identical to the question I asked. I would appreciate a new solution which puts the section title and horizontal rule in the margin as well as the theorems etc

Comment: Also, in case there is some confusion, I would like all the text in that section to be separated from the theorem titles and numbers, not just the text in the theorems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `paracol` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
%Underlining ruler for subsections
\titleformat{\section}%
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% format
  {}% label
  {0mm}% sep
  {%
    \vadjust pre{%
      \color{gray}%
      \hrule width \linewidth height 0.5pt\relax
    }%
  }% before-code



\begin{document}
\columnratio{0.3}
\begin{paracol}{2}[\section{Example Section}]

\begin{thm}
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{thm}

\switchcolumn 
Some text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\switchcolumn 
\begin{mydef}
Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
\end{mydef}

\switchcolumn 
Some other text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]